# merging multiple files using UNIX AWK OR JOIN

Tags: unix, join, awk

I have about 12 files.. Few of them are like

file 1

```
aaaaa 10/25/2012 10/30/2012
aaaaa 10/30/2012 11/15/2013
aaaaa 11/15/2013 07/04/2013
bbbbb 06/06/2013 04/08/2014
ccccc 01/01/2014 06/09/2014
```

file 2

```
aaaaa 10/25/2012 10/30/2012
aaaaa 10/30/2012 11/15/2013
aaaaa 11/15/2013 07/04/2013
bbbbb 06/06/2013 04/08/2014
```

file 3

```
aaaaa 10/25/2012 10/30/2012
aaaaa 11/15/2013 07/04/2013
bbbbb 06/06/2013 04/08/2014
ccccc 01/01/2014 06/09/2014
```

.....

file 9

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

file 10

```
aaaaa
bbbbb
```

file 11

```
aaaaa
ccccc
```

There are all sorted. File 1 is like a master file. I would like to compare file 1 with file 2 on three columns. File 1 with file 3..etc.. until file 8. From file 9 thru 11, I want to compare on file1 with file 9 for example on first column.

I want a output like this

I want a output like this(Please see attachment it is better)

```
id     date1        date2          existFile2    existFile3............................existFile9.....existFile10.......existfile11
aaaaa 10/25/2012 10/30/2012        Y             Y                                     Y          Y                  Y
aaaaa 10/30/2012 11/15/2013        Y             N                                     Y              Y                  Y
aaaaa 11/15/2013 07/04/2013        Y             Y                                     Y              Y                  Y
bbbbb 06/06/2013 04/08/2014        Y             Y                                     Y              Y                  N
ccccc 01/01/2014 06/09/2014        N             Y                                     Y              N                  Y
```

I am new to awk and join of unix..so trying to experiment.

Answer (score 1):

My solution is the following awk code (put it in file 'merge.awk'):

```
(NR == FNR) {keys[$0] = $0}

(NR != FNR) && ($0 in keys) {
  result[FILENAME $0] = "Y"
}

END {
  printf("                      ")
  for (i = 1; i < ARGC; i++) {
    printf("%s   ",ARGV[i])
  }
  printf("\n")

  for (key in keys) {
    printf("%s     ", key)
    for (i = 2; i < ARGC; i++) {
      r = result[ARGV[i] key]
      if (r == "") r = "N"
      printf("%s       ",r)
    }
    printf("\n")
  }
}
```

The key concept is to distinguish records from the first file from others using `NR == FNR` condition. See [this manual](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/gawk/gawk_11.html#SEC108) for reference. And then I used awk arrays to do the heavy lifting ;-)

I have used the following files to test my solution:

```
::::::::::::::
file1
::::::::::::::
aaaaa 10/25/2012 10/30/2012
aaaaa 10/30/2012 11/15/2013
aaaaa 11/15/2013 07/04/2013
bbbbb 06/06/2013 04/08/2014
ccccc 01/01/2014 06/09/2014
::::::::::::::
file2
::::::::::::::
aaaaa 10/25/2012 10/30/2012
aaaaa 10/30/2012 11/15/2013
aaaaa 11/15/2013 07/04/2013
bbbbb 06/06/2013 04/08/2014
::::::::::::::
file3
::::::::::::::
aaaaa 10/25/2012 10/30/2012
aaaaa 11/15/2013 07/04/2013
bbbbb 06/06/2013 04/08/2014
ccccc 01/01/2014 06/09/2014
::::::::::::::
file4
::::::::::::::
aaaaa
bbbbb
ccccc
```

So command `awk -f merge.awk file1 file2 file3 file4` should give the following result:

```
                      file1   file2   file3   file4   
aaaaa 11/15/2013 07/04/2013     Y       Y       N       
aaaaa 10/30/2012 11/15/2013     Y       N       N       
aaaaa 10/25/2012 10/30/2012     Y       Y       N       
bbbbb 06/06/2013 04/08/2014     Y       Y       N       
ccccc 01/01/2014 06/09/2014     N       Y       N
```